# Cant log supportedPreviewSizes() in Java

Tags: java, android-camera

Hi I have a Javascript background and am learning Java... trying to simply output what the supportedPreviewSizes are but I only get a format like this:

```java
android.hardware.Camera$Size@27eefd0
```

I need to get the width and height. I had tried this:

```
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = cParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

for (int i = 0; i < previewSizes.size(); i++)
{
    // if the size is suitable for you, use it and exit the loop.
    Log.d("previewSize", previewSizes.get(0).toString());
    break;
}
```

I don't know why this is so damn hard in Java it doesn't seem intuitive at all. Javascript is way more intuitive console.log(your Object) wow so easy!

Comment: this might help you [LINK] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477253/android-how-to-use-camera-getsupportedpreviewsizes-for-portrait-orientation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Camera.Size`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size) class doesn't override `toString()`, so you get the default implementation, which, as you've seen, isn't very useful. You'll have to manually log the height and the width:

```
for (int i = 0; i < previewSizes.size(); i++)
{
    Camera.Size ps = previewSizes.get(i);
    Log.d("previewSize", "height: " + ps.height + ", width: " + ps.width);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's quite difficult to do the basics when just starting out.

Comment: previewSizes(i) should be previewSizes.get(i) for any readers...

Comment: @MichaelPaccione indeed - sloppy typing on my behalf, sorry about that. Edited and fixed.